# How to rotate an Image inside PictureBox by 20 degrees VB 2015?

Tags: vb.net, rotation, image-rotation

Say, i have a PictureBox1 in my Form. That PictureBox have an Image in it, and I want to rotate it. Actually, I've learn how to rotate the image by 90,180,270.... degree. But how can I rotate it by 20 degrees or 45 degrees?

This is what I've learn

```
 PictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone)
```

Comment: You need to use the GDI methods to do this. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58815/C-Image-PictureBox-Rotations)

Comment: YOU may have your answer in this [Topic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e8fccfc0-10e4-44bf-97d4-601b22908835/rotate-picturebox-image-at-25-degree-using-vbnet-2008?forum=vbgeneral)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotating an Image in a picture box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431154/rotating-an-image-in-a-picture-box)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
Public Function RotateImage(ByRef image As Image, ByVal offset As PointF, ByVal angle As Decimal) As Bitmap
    If image Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("image")
    End If
    ''create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image
    Dim rotatedBmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height)
    'Dim rotatedBmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(image)
    rotatedBmp.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution)
    ''make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedBmp)
    ''Put the rotation point in the center of the image
    g.TranslateTransform(offset.X, offset.Y)
    ''rotate the image
    g.RotateTransform(angle)
    ''move the image back
    g.TranslateTransform(-offset.X, -offset.Y)
    ''draw passed in image onto graphics object
    'g.DrawImage(image, New PointF(0, 0))
    g.DrawImage(image, offset)
    Return rotatedBmp
End Function
```

Comment: How can this formatting gore help someone? Please format your answer and add some epxplanational words. Thanks.