# Rotating an Image in a picture box

Tags: .net, vb.net, image

I am currently writing a game which uses an arrow which needs to rotate in order to tell the user at what angle they will "throw" their boule. I have coded almost all of the solution however, I have the arrow as a picture box and an image inside of it. I need to be able to rotate in and record at what angle it has been rotated, I have a timer which I plan to rotate the image one degree each time it ticks and add one to the angle variable. The only thing I struggle with is actually rotating the image. Any further details you require I can give,

Any help is much appreciated,
Many Thanks,
Dan

```
Private Function RotateImage(image As Image, angle As Single) As Bitmap
    ' the calling code is responsible for (and must) 
    ' disposing of the bitmap returned

    Dim retBMP As New Bitmap(image)
    retBMP.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution)

    Using g = Graphics.FromImage(retBMP)
        ' rotate aroung the center of the image
        g.TranslateTransform(image.Width \ 2, image.Height \ 2)

        'rotate
        g.RotateTransform(angle)

        g.TranslateTransform(-image.Width \ 2, -image.Height \ 2)

        'draw image to the new boitmap
        g.DrawImage(retBMP, New PointF(0, 0))
    End Using
    Return retBMP
End Function


Private Sub PowerTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PowerTimer.Tick

    If ArrowAngle >= 45 Then
        AngleIncreasing = False
    ElseIf ArrowAngle <= -45 Then
        AngleIncreasing = True
    End If
    If AngleIncreasing = True Then
        Arrow.Image = New Bitmap(Arrow.Image)
        Arrow.Image = RotateImage(Arrow.Image, 1)
        Me.Refresh()
        ArrowAngle = ArrowAngle + 1
    Else
        Arrow.Image = RotateImage(Arrow.Image, 1)
        Arrow.Image = RotateImage(Arrow.Image, -1)
        Me.Refresh()
        ArrowAngle = ArrowAngle - 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you do any research at all?  The first google search for this returns the MSDN write up for the `RotateFlip` method.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, I have done research but you should know that the RotateFlip method can't do values of things such as 1 degree, It can do 90, 180 and all other major values but I do not believe it can do one degree. Correct me if I am wrong and show some exemplar code but I do not believe that this method will work for my implementation. Just so you know I have also looked into image graphics (The drawing) but it seemed a little to inefficient just to rotate an arrow.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58815/C-Image-PictureBox-Rotations

Comment: This does not appear to work, I am using Visual Studio a vb.net (Hence the tag) form application. The link provided is for C# I have attempted to turn it into VB.Net Code but it argues that Utilities is undefined.

Comment: One of the comments says it appears to translate into VB.NET very well.  Which line are you hanging up on?

Comment: pictureBox.Image = Utilities.RotateImage(image, 35);

Comment: `Utilities` is the name of the class. If you put the `RotateImage` function in the same form class, just use `me.RotateImage(image,35)`

Comment: It says RotateImage is not a member of Form1

Comment: Show where you added that method.

Comment: Into a sub in Form1. More specifically they timer tick event for the ArrowTimer

Comment: I mean add the code to your post where you declared the entire RotateImage private method.

Comment: It's a typing error, while copying it I realized by reference to the method was spelt wrong. Apologies, it should work now - will do some testing and let you know

Comment: Unsure how to add code as the ` symbols don't seem to work. But there are no errors unsure whether there will be any logic errors though.

Comment: Paste all the code and then click the { } button

Comment: No, you need to add it to your original post.

Comment: Arrow.Image = Me.RotateImage(Arrow.Image, New Point(124, 202), 1)        This is an example call to rotate about image 1 degree about the point (124,202)

Comment: Hmmm.  Several things: a) the if/else for `AngleIncreasing` arent the same - one creates a new bitmap, the other just does a -1, 1 rotation; b) you arent disposing of the old image as the answer warns, so your app is leaking and will crash eventually c) too many images - rather than trying to incrementally rotate, increment the angle.  Some of the trouble could be what you are using for an image - you may need to doctor it for this use.

Comment: This needs to be finished today and the only thing remaining to fix is moving the arrow back and forth on a timer between 45 and -45 degrees. Please attach the code you used for your arrow.

Answer (score 12):

There are several issues with [the original code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58815/C-Image-PictureBox-Rotations) and the VB translation.  First, `CreateGraphics` is almost never the right thing to use.  Right after that, it is replaced with one from `Graphics.FromImage`.  This is the right way, since you will be drawing to a bitmap, but neither one is disposed, so the app will leak.  This could be a problem if something is rotating on a timer.

Second, the c# version is flawed: the method expects an offset to be passed but that can be calculated ("How To Use" doest bother to pass an offset).  Finally, the c# version is also leaking.

```
Private Function RotateImage(img As Image, angle As Single) As Bitmap
    ' the calling code is responsible for (and must) 
    ' disposing of the bitmap returned

    Dim retBMP As New Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height)
    retBMP.SetResolution(img.HorizontalResolution, img.VerticalResolution)

    Using g = Graphics.FromImage(retBMP)
        ' rotate aroung the center of the image
        g.TranslateTransform(img.Width \ 2, img.Height \ 2)

        'rotate
        g.RotateTransform(angle)

        g.TranslateTransform(-img.Width \ 2, -img.Height \ 2)

        'draw image to the bitmap
        g.DrawImage(img, New PointF(0, 0))

        Return retBMP
    End Using
End Function
```

Usage:

```
' form level var if rotating over and over
Private CatImg As Bitmap

' elsewhere:
CatImg = New Bitmap("C:\Temp\ceiling_cat.jpg")

' to create a new rotated image:
 Dim bmp = RotateImage(CatImg, -65)
 pb1.Image = bmp

 'ToDo: dispose of the picbox image
```

Results (before and after):

[image]

The corners are clipped because your code does not calculate a new bounding rectangle size.  If the thing rotating is inside a larger image, it could still work.

---

Using the Rotate method to redirect an arrow back and forth -90 to 90 degrees on a timer:

[image]

Smoooth! A lot will depend on the nature of the image to be rotated, and we know nothing about the image in this case.  A glance at TaskManager showed nothing leaking - be sure to dispose of the previous image.

Comment: Using this code and can add it to my original post if required but it's drawing onto the old image putting both on screen and as I am rotating a lot this causes the picture box to just fill in red. Any ideas?

Comment: Of course, I have no idea what your image looks like or how red factors into it.  The method returns a **new** image rotated from the original, so if it  is drawing to a previous one, it is how you are using it.  Is this supposed to be a clock like thing (you mentioned a 1 degree rotation) which seems extravagant.

Comment: The image is red, it's an arrow that is red. I'll put my current code into the original post