# My image in a picture box is not rotating on keypressed

Tags: vb.net

I am doing a car parking game.i am using the arrow keys to move it,but when the down key is pressed,the picture box does not move down.Also ,when the right or up keys are pressed,the picture box does not stop.I want also to rotate the car while moving right or left.I tried but was not able.

```
 Private Sub Timerdiagonalright_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timerdiagonalright.Tick
    RotateImage(pbcar1.Image, 20)

End Sub



Private Function RotateImage(img As Image, angle As Single) As Bitmap
    ' the calling code is responsible for (and must) 
    ' disposing of the bitmap returned

    Dim retBMP As New Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height)
    retBMP.SetResolution(img.HorizontalResolution, img.VerticalResolution)

    Using g = Graphics.FromImage(retBMP)
        ' rotate aroung the center of the image
        g.TranslateTransform(img.Width \ 2, img.Height \ 2)

        'rotate
        g.RotateTransform(angle)

        g.TranslateTransform(-img.Width \ 2, -img.Height \ 2)

        'draw image to the bitmap
        g.DrawImage(img, New PointF(0, 0))

        Return retBMP
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: There sure is a lot of students from Mauritius having trouble [parking the car](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44391408/1070452) today.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Please help me,i did my best

Comment: @Plutonix please tell me what is wrong with my down key and how to rotate the car while moving,please

Comment: Please read [Ask] and take the [tour].  `RotateFlipType` is not a valid location put your mouse on it and press F1

Comment: @Plutonix, i took the tour and read about how to ask,sorry if i did not ask well,i know i have put all the code,but only for you to understand well.i won't repeat the same mistake again.Can you please tell me how to rotate the car left or right while moving?should i insert a timer to move diagonally?Please tell me,why me down arrow key is not working :( thanks

Comment: LOL @Plutonix, homework help?  @MuhammadNadir  is it hitting this line `If pbcar1.Location.Y > Me.Height Then`  - the issue may be in that condition, me.height would be referring to the height of your form, yes?

Comment: @JimmySmith   yes,i put a breakpoint,and its hiiting it,the value of me.height is 366 and that of x and y are 191,187.

Comment: @MuhammadNadir there ya go!  It's in the fact of what conditions(bad condition) it has to meet in order to `movedown()`  What if, you change that line to `If pbcar1.Location.Y < Me.Height Then`  does it work better?

Comment: yes,it works,thank you  @JimmySmith. can you please tell me how to rotate the picturebox left or right while moving up?please

Comment: @JimmySmith,  i change  the way of rotation by using rotate transform and translate transform,but there is no rotation change to the picture box when a key is pressed .Please help

Comment: @Plutonix please help me.there is no rotation change

Comment: Your title no longer matches the problem you are talking about in comments (which reduces the chance of someone answering) See [Rotating an Image in a picture box](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40431154/1070452) I am not sure why you would want it on a timer - it could flip back mid course

Answer (score 0):

If the image is already loaded to your PictureBox, your can use

```
PictureBox.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType)
```

to rotate your image.

Please note that this is not an efficient way to do animated graphics; to improve performance a little when moving controls, consider reading on SuspendLayout / ResumeLayout and BeginUpdate / EndUpdate.